How to connect React Vite app with .NET Aspire Api?
I have a solution which contains an ASP.NET Core Web API as backend, and a React Vite frontend. I am experimenting with the new .NET Aspire and I am struggling to get the "auto reference" to work.
Here is my Aspire program.cs:
 var api = builder.AddProject<Projects.MyApp_Home_Api_se>("myapphomeapise")
    .WithReference(database)
    .WaitFor(database)
    .WithHttpEndpoint(3010, 8080, "api");

builder.AddNpmApp("myapp-home-se", "../MyApp.Home.se", "dev")
    .WithReference(api)
    .WaitFor(api)
    .WithEnvironment("BROWSER", "none")
    .WithEnvironment("VITE_API_URL", $"http://localhost:{api.GetEndpoint("api").TargetPort.ToString()}")
    .WithHttpEndpoint(env: "VITE_PORT")
    .WithExternalHttpEndpoints()
    .PublishAsDockerFile();

I get the environment variable: services__myapphomeapise__api__0, but since it doesn't start with the prefix VITE_, I don't think I can access that variable in my Vite frontend. I tried to make an ugly mapping as you see in my code above with the WithEnvironment but it doesn't really work for the mapping in production..
Thanks in advance!
Best regards Max
